# How to find the terminal command executed by any mouse event

Tags: command-line, mouse

I mean for example if I am clicking a button in Firefox (or any other event) what is the terminal command that is being executed?

Yes I do know there is `apropos` but I am asking is there something like if I hover over something it would just tell you what terminal command it *would* execute if clicked?

Comment: You have a too simple impression of what is happening. In many cases, there is no external cli command for such actions, simply because the application doesn' t offer one.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I know I have a simple impression of what happening that's why I want to know what would happen :) something is going to be triggered on an event so even if the app is listening to it self for events it have to send some thing to the system to change status I guess?

Comment: A user (cli) command is in a language by definition. Not everything that happens is "catchable" that way. Status change does not mean that *you* can do it in a command, simply because the command isn't available from outside the application.

Comment: Basically, when you click on a button in an application, the application internally decides what to do, according to its program (as written by the programmer who wrote it). It may be to run a command, as in the case of an desktop icon or menu item, but it may be something else, such as to display a menu, as in the case of a menu bar item.

Comment: @Talal: thanks for the acceptance. Question clarified (and upvoted) so that the next user having the same problem will be helped too.  It might be beneficial to you to [ask another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and explain what you're trying to accomplish because maybe there is a bunch of terminal commands that can be made to do what you're trying to do!  **;-)**

Comment: @muru the dupe should have been the other way around (this one is older)  **:P *-)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is best explained by an example:

1. Take the simplest C program in the world:

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    main()
    {
      printf("Hello World!");
    }
```

2. Take the simplest `bash` program in the world:

```bsh
    #!/usr/bin/env bash          
    echo "Hello World!"
```

Now place both programs on an icon on the launcher.

Although both programs have the exact same effect on your Ubuntu system, in the second case, we can say that the terminal command being executed is `echo "Hello World!"`.

*However,* in the first case, there just is no terminal command being executed as the terminal isn't involved  *at all!* Unfortunately for you, most of the stuff inside Ubuntu (drawing menus, drawing icons, displaying a cell in a spreadsheet, right-clicking a word in a document, ...)  doesn't involve the terminal at all.

Comment: Je haalt me de woorden uit de mond. Very nice example :)